Standardize Excel Files with Changing Headers using Python?
I'm trying to see if it's possible to use Python + a web interface to take files with non-standard headers, upload them, and spit out a standardized file. Ex.



FN
LN




John
Doe


Jane
Doe






FstNm
LstNm




John
Doe


Jane
Doe






First_Name
Last_Name




John
Doe


Jane
Doe



etc etc.
I have a lot of files being sent with no standard header. Is there a way that all 3 of these files could be imported into a web tool where a script runs in the background to rename the headers to "First_Name" and "Last_Name"?
I'm fairly new to Python, so thus far all I've done is try to research the feasibility of this.

what is the workflow?

 def process_file(file):
    # Read the uploaded file into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    
    # Convert all column headers to lowercase
    df.columns = [col.lower() for col in df.columns]
    
    # Search for headers containing "f" or "l" and replace them with "First_Name" and "Last_Name"
    new_columns = []
    for col in df.columns:
        new_col = col
        if 'f' in col:
            new_col = 'first_name'
        if 'l' in col:
            new_col = 'last_name'
        new_columns.append(new_col)
    
    df.columns = new_columns
    
    # Write the modified DataFrame to an Excel file
    output = BytesIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
    writer.save()
    output.seek(0)
    
    return output

